# addClass to specific element

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I created a list (li) and I want to add a specific class to that list

```
<ul class="main">
 <li></li>
 <li> 
   <span class="ext"></span>
   <ul>
     <li> 
       <span class="ext"></span>
     </li>
   </ul>
 <li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class to only that `first ul > second li > first span` class but for some reasons it is also adding it to that span class under the second ul.

This is the code I'm using to add the class

```
$('ul.main li:nth-child(2) .ext').addClass('another-ext')
```

Snippet:

```js
$('ul.main li:nth-child(2) .ext').addClass('another-ext')
```

```css
.another-ext {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <span class="ext"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="ext">hello</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef read the question once again, you targeted bad `.ext` :-) But the point of using `>` is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use children selector. It should work.

```js
$('ul.main > li:nth-child(2) > .ext').addClass('another-ext')
```

```css
.another-ext {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
 <li>A</li>
 <li> 
   <span class="ext">B</span>
   <ul>
     <li> 
       <span class="ext">C</span>
     </li>
   </ul>
 <li>D
</ul>
```